# How to update selected rows of spatial data frame in R

Tags: r, sp

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame read via rgdal::readOGR

```
require(rgdal)
my_sp_layer <- readOGR(dsn="my_dsn", layer="my_layer_file")

# select rows using col_attrib column
my_sp_layer@data[my_sp_layer@data$col_attrib == 'some value',]
```

How can I update the values of the selected rows?

If it is a data.table, I would just use

```
my_data_table[col_attrib == 'some value', col_to_update := 'new value']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert the column you want to amend to `character` as this will be set to `factor` by default:

```
shapefile@data$column_update <- as.character(shapefile@data$column_update)
```

Then just select the column you want to update with subset notation (`[` `]`) and use assign `<-`:

```
Shapefile@data$column_update[shapefile@data$column_condition == "condition"] <- " new_value"
```

Comment: I got NA's for the selected rows instead of a new value with the following warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, Julita_more_hazard@data$Legend == "damaged culvert",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @JunFolledo See edited answer. If this still doesn't solve it please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Phil, it's now working after converting it to character, so I guest the readOGR must have been converted the character column as factor, am I right?

Comment: @JunFolledo That's right, that's `readOGR()`'s default behaviour.